# How to parse a complex JSON with LogicApps and Key/Value pairs

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a fairly complex JSON coming from Microsoft D365 Events where I need to derive some fields from to save it into a SQL Server. I want to use Logic Apps for that. Since I'm not sure about schema drifts, I don't want to use Indexes to address the fields, I would like to leverage the Keys in the JSON.
This is a (very much shortened) JSON sample:

```
[
    {
        "key": "Target",
        "value": {
            "__type": "Entity:http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts",
            "Id": "00000000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "KeyAttributes": [],
            "LogicalName": "mserp_custcustomerv2entity",
            "RowVersion": null,
            "Attributes": [
                {
                    "key": "mserp_customeraccount",
                    "value": "FA-001"
                },
                {
                    "key": "mserp_partytype",
                    "value": "Organization"
                },
                {
                    "key": "mserp_organizationname",
                    "value": "Fabric US"
                },
                {
                    "key": "mserp_namealias",
                    "value": "Fabric US"
                },
                {
                    "key": "mserp_knownas",
                    "value": ""
                },
                {
                    "key": "mserp_customergroupid",
                    "value": "30"
                },
                {
                    "key": "mserp_organizationnumber",
                    "value": ""
                },
                {
                    "key": "mserp_organizationnumberofemployees",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "key": "mserp_organizationabccode",
                    "value": {
                        "__type": "OptionSetValue:http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts",
                        "Value": 200000000
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "mserp_custcustomerv2entityid",
                    "value": "00000000-0000-0000-000000000000"
                }
            ],
            "EntityState": null,
            "FormattedValues": [
                {
                    "key": "mserp_dataareaid_id",
                    "value": "USMF"
                }
            ],
            "RelatedEntities": []
        }
    },
    {
        "key": "PreImage",
        "value": {
            "__type": "Entity:http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts",
            "Id": "00000000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "KeyAttributes": [],
            "LogicalName": "mserp_custcustomerv2entity",
            "RowVersion": null,
            "Attributes": [
                {
                    "key": "mserp_customeraccount",
                    "value": "FA-001"
                },
                {
                    "key": "mserp_partytype",
                    "value": "Organization"
                },
                {
                    "key": "mserp_organizationname",
                    "value": "Fabric US"
                },
                {
                    "key": "mserp_namealias",
                    "value": "Fabric US"
                },
                {
                    "key": "mserp_knownas",
                    "value": ""
                },
                {
                    "key": "mserp_customergroupid",
                    "value": "30"
                },
                {
                    "key": "mserp_organizationnumber",
                    "value": ""
                },
                {
                    "key": "mserp_organizationnumberofemployees",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "key": "mserp_organizationabccode",
                    "value": {
                        "__type": "OptionSetValue:http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts",
                        "Value": 200000000
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "mserp_custcustomerv2entityid",
                    "value": "00000000-0000-0000-000000000000"
                }
            ],
            "EntityState": null,
            "FormattedValues": [
                {
                    "key": "mserp_dataareaid_id",
                    "value": "USMF"
                }
            ],
            "RelatedEntities": []
        }
    },
    {
        "key": "ChangedFields",
        "value": []
    }
]
```

I found some references using looping and filtering out the different fields but that would be a quite complex thing to manage.

I would like to have some "path" based on the keys I can somehow use in Logic Apps, preferred with a build-in action to have the different fields from the JSON easily in variables so that I can use them easily to bring it i.e. into a SQL Server with the standard SQL action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said ...

> preferred with a build-in action ...

... and bottom line, there's nothing simple when it comes to converting all of that key value pair data to an array of objects.

I have two approaches for you though.

#### Select Using XPath

You can use a select and XPath expressions to extract the data.  It's quick but verbose AND it won't work dynamically.  If a new attribute is added, it won't do the conversion for you and include that attribute automatically.

[image: Select]

This is the code view for the `Select` step ...

```
{
    "inputs": {
        "from": "@outputs('Compose')",
        "select": {
            "mserp_customeraccount": "@first(xpath(xml(json(concat('{ \"root\": { \"item\": ', item(), '}}'))), '//Attributes[key=\"mserp_customeraccount\"]/value[1]/text()'))",
            "mserp_customergroupid": "@first(xpath(xml(json(concat('{ \"root\": { \"item\": ', item(), '}}'))), '//Attributes[key=\"mserp_customergroupid\"]/value[1]/text()'))",
            "mserp_knownas": "@first(xpath(xml(json(concat('{ \"root\": { \"item\": ', item(), '}}'))), '//Attributes[key=\"mserp_knownas\"]/value[1]/text()'))",
            "mserp_namealias": "@first(xpath(xml(json(concat('{ \"root\": { \"item\": ', item(), '}}'))), '//Attributes[key=\"mserp_namealias\"]/value[1]/text()'))",
            "mserp_organizationname": "@first(xpath(xml(json(concat('{ \"root\": { \"item\": ', item(), '}}'))), '//Attributes[key=\"mserp_organizationname\"]/value[1]/text()'))",
            "mserp_organizationnumber": "@first(xpath(xml(json(concat('{ \"root\": { \"item\": ', item(), '}}'))), '//Attributes[key=\"mserp_organizationnumber\"]/value[1]/text()'))",
            "mserp_organizationnumberofemployees": "@first(xpath(xml(json(concat('{ \"root\": { \"item\": ', item(), '}}'))), '//Attributes[key=\"mserp_organizationnumberofemployees\"]/value[1]/text()'))",
            "mserp_partytype": "@first(xpath(xml(json(concat('{ \"root\": { \"item\": ', item(), '}}'))), '//Attributes[key=\"mserp_partytype\"]/value[1]/text()'))"
        }
    }
}
```

#### Execute Javascript Code

You can use the in-line Javascript operation to run some code over your data to get the desired outcome.  This will work dynamically but requires an integration account.  That's not the biggest deal, just something to note.

[image: Javascript]

This is the code ...

```
var jsonData = workflowContext.actions.Compose.inputs;

// Initialize an empty object to store the processed data
const processedDataArray = [];

// Loop through the JSON data
jsonData.forEach((item) => {
  if (item.key === "Target" || item.key === "PreImage") {
    // Find the "Attributes" section
    const attributes = item.value.Attributes;

    // Initialize an empty object to store the processed attributes
    const processedAttributes = {};

    // Loop through the attributes and convert them into key-value pairs in the processedAttributes object
    attributes.forEach((attribute) => {
      processedAttributes[attribute.key] = attribute.value;
    });

    // Push the processedAttributes object to the processedDataArray
    processedDataArray.push(processedAttributes);
  }
});

return processedDataArray;
```

This is the output, which you may need to clean up depending on the type of value that each property holds ...

```
[
  {
    "mserp_customeraccount": "FA-001",
    "mserp_partytype": "Organization",
    "mserp_organizationname": "Fabric US",
    "mserp_namealias": "Fabric US",
    "mserp_knownas": "",
    "mserp_customergroupid": "30",
    "mserp_organizationnumber": "",
    "mserp_organizationnumberofemployees": 0,
    "mserp_organizationabccode": {
      "Value": 200000000,
      "__type": "OptionSetValue:http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts"
    },
    "mserp_custcustomerv2entityid": "00000000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  },
  {
    "mserp_customeraccount": "FA-001",
    "mserp_partytype": "Organization",
    "mserp_organizationname": "Fabric US",
    "mserp_namealias": "Fabric US",
    "mserp_knownas": "",
    "mserp_customergroupid": "30",
    "mserp_organizationnumber": "",
    "mserp_organizationnumberofemployees": 0,
    "mserp_organizationabccode": {
      "Value": 200000000,
      "__type": "OptionSetValue:http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts"
    },
    "mserp_custcustomerv2entityid": "00000000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  }
]
```

Comment: You hare the hero of my day :-) THANKS for the two options... I tried Option 2 first (I love the flexibility) but I have some issues consuming the results in further actions... So how do I reference it? Do I need to add another "Parse JSON" for it, but i would then loose the flexibility I gained compared to Option 1... Sorry, for the beginners-question :-)

Comment: It depends on how dynamic you want it to be so really, you’ve answered your own question. Dynamic content is static in nature in that it's only really good to you at design time, so the answer to your question is yes, you’d need to use another Parse JSON if you wanted dynamic content as an option, but again, it’ll expect a schema and subsequently lose the dynamic aspect of the processing if new properties are added later on. Up to you as I’m not sure how fluid your resulting json will be. Also, do me a favour and mark it as the answer if you’re happy, ta.